# Placing text next to image

Tags: php, html, css

Why is my text not going to the right next to my image? I have tried putting all of it in 1 div but that doesn't work either.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mijnModel<?=$row['ID'];?>" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $row ['product_naam'] ?></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" style="height: auto;">
            <img src="/product_images/<?php echo $row ['product_afbeelding'] ?>" style="width:250px; height:250px;">
            <h2 style="margin-left: 350px; float: right;">Prijs: <?php echo "<td>" . "€" . $row['product_prijs'] . "</td>"; ?></h2>
            <br>
            <p style="margin-left: 350px;float: right; margin-top: -50px;"><strong>Omschrijving:</strong>
                <?php echo "<td>" . $row[ 'product_omschrijving'] . "</td>"; ?>
            </p>
            <br>
            <p><strong>Specificaties:</strong>
                <?php echo "<td>" . $row[ 'product_specs'] . "</td>"; ?>
            </p>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float image content right. Failing that use bootstrap and use a container row and column. This will make it much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute and margin-left:350px;

```
<h2 style="margin-left: 350px;position: absolute;">Prijs: <?php echo "<td>" . "€" . $row['product_prijs'] . "</td>"; ?></h2>
```